# List all devices in wlan via javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I'm using phonegap/cordova to program a mobile app and I want to list all devices that are connected in the same network as the client.
Phonegap only supports `html`, `css`,`javascript`, `ajax` and jquery.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplace of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459029/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-user-is-on-a-wifi-connection-with-php-or-javascrip

Comment: there are some hacking techniques that can reveal network devices. you can port scan via img pings and look for default images from known http-connected devices. there is not clean simple way though...